# How to add validation rules to jQuery Validation Plug-in

Tags: jquery

I have added the additional-methods.js in my project that overrides the jQuery Validation Plugin, but I don't know how to configure it in order to get the right message for this element. I am trying to apply the phoneUK regex found in the document here.

[jQuery Validation Plugin - adding rules that apply to multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829030/jquery-validation-plugin-adding-rules-that-apply-to-multiple-fields)

Do I need to add this .js in the html script?
If so how can I use its methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after trying some stuff in my projects. I just needed to call the write methods in the validator.js that validates the form for me.

```
phoneUK: true
```

is enough to make it work.