# jQuery Validation : Regex for input name value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I am trying to add validation for a form

```
$('#reportForm').validate({
    rules: {
      'report[invoices_attributes][0][invoice_type]' :
  {
    required: true,
    'report[invoices_attributes][0][invoice_type]':true

  }
  }
  });
```

reportForm is the id of my form. All of my input fields name values will be like `'report[invoices_attributes][indexnr]...'` ( as I am using nesting attributes and there can be 0 or more elements )

For this, I want to match the input name value for all with a regex like : `/^report\[invoices_attributes\]\[[0-9]\](.*)/`

How can this be added to the rule field for input name value (currently `'report[invoices_attributes][0][invoice_type]'`), to match all the fields I'm interested in ?

Comment: You cannot do it like that.  When declaring rules inside of the `rules` object of `.validate()`, you can only declare the rule one field at a time.  You also cannot have a layout where all fields being validated share the same `name` attribute.  Each field must have a unique `name`.  Or a single "grouping" of checkboxes/radio buttons can share a `name`.  This is all spelled out in the documentation.

Comment: And under each `name` in your scenario can only be a listing of rules, not more field names.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would [entirely avoid Allman style code formatting in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11247362/594235).

---

When declaring rules inside of the `rules` object of `.validate()`, you can only declare the rule one field at a time...

```
$('#reportForm').validate({
    rules: {
        'report[invoices_attributes][0][invoice_type]': {
            required: true,
        },
        'report[invoices_attributes][1][invoice_type]': {
            required: true,
        },
        'report[invoices_attributes][2][invoice_type]': {
            required: true,
        },
        // etc.
    }
});
```

If you want to declare on multiple fields, then use the `.rules()` method along with a jQuery `.each()` and any appropriate jQuery selector that will target your group.

```
$('.myfields').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
});
```

You also cannot have a layout where all fields being validated share the same `name` attribute. **Each field must have a unique `name`.** Or a single "grouping" of checkboxes/radio buttons can share a `name`.  **There is no workaround for this.**

If you're only needing basic rules that can simply be declared by boolean, then you can use inline attributes instead of `.rules()` method or `rules` object.

```
<input name="foo" required="required" ....
```

alternatively by class...

```
<input name="foo" class="required" ....
```

More info:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056425/594235